On the exchange of sums and derivatives of probability functions of the Poisson distribution
Problem
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\right) \overset{?}{=} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{d\lambda}\left( \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\right)
$$
It can be easily shown by expanding and computing the left and right sides, respectively, but in this case we would like to consider a proof of other generality.
What I know
The condition for term-wise differentiation is that the probability function should converge uniformly:
$$
f_n(\lambda):=\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\to 1=:f\ (\mathrm{uniformly})
$$
Is this correct? Also, how can this be shown?

Are you sure $f_n$ converges to $1$?

The series is absolutely convergent, the ability to exchange summation and differentiation follows from that, no?

The LHS of the first equation is 0 if it helps
